# How does the browser diffierentate between two identical HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

In an HTML page where you have two elements that are exactly the same;

```
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

How does the browser differentiate between these two elements internally? Here is a working example of the browser being able to do so: https://jsfiddle.net/t9rvyhoc/

I'm assuming it's some sort of unique ID. If so, is that property accessible to me?

Comment: The sequencing is the only way to get. That is you could get it by **index**.

Comment: In what way would you want to differentiate? When the DOM tree is built, these just become two successive nodes.

Comment: It don't have **some unique ID**, rather it has the **node `index(es)`**. Starting from `0` as the first one.

Comment: In the browser's memory, they're two different nodes that are stored in different memory locations. It's like how a C program can differentiate between different array elements, even if they contain the same values.

Comment: Thanks, the node index is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Browser differentiates them mainly by their unique position in the DOM tree. Each single tag in your document, once parsed, gets its unique position in the internal representation of that documents in the browser's memory - DOM (document object model), which is a tree-like structure. Browser identifies this tag by its position in the tree (how exactly it does that is typically hidden from us? What we have is a DOM tree). There is no explicit ID associated with each tag, however, you may address every element on the page (no matter whether they have ID or not) simply by their position in the tree - i.e. their parent tags and the position of a given tag among its siblings - both with CSS (via constructs like `body p em` and `::nth-child()`) and with JavaScript (via DOM traversal).

When you attach an event handler to any given element, and that event fires (for example, you have two buttons, attach a click handler only to the second one, and a user clicks that second button), your event handleк function receives an event data (a note from browser describing what exactly happened), and somewhere among that data you will typically find a reference to the DOM element where this event happened (i.e. in our example a reference to the DOM element that represents that second button - and you still may traverse the DOM tree from that reference, e.g. Know its parents, siblings etc).

Answer (score 0):

There is always the nth-child property in css..

```
.item:nth-child(2) {

background-color: red;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
 color:white;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t9rvyhoc/1/)

Comment: $( ".item:nth-child(1)" ) could be used as well